# Problem in calculating inverse of two nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation

i have two nested list named t1 as follows

```
t1={{{-5.95333, -6.28989, 1.78237,  0.0765267, -0.301329}, {-6.28989, -159.769, 1.92113, 1.96052,  2.37397}, {1.78237, 1.92113, -0.788266, -0.0239211,  0.17575}, {0.0765267,  1.96052, -0.0239211, -0.0272567, -0.0197437}, {-0.301329, 2.37397,  0.17575, -0.0197437, -1.09727}}, {{-5.55721, -2.09198, 0.841045,  0.124068, -0.452792}, {-2.09198, -51.929, 0.336034, 2.81105, 0.948832}, {0.841045, 0.336034, -0.14926, -0.0195627,  0.0503916}, {0.124068,  2.81105, -0.0195627, -0.195508, -0.0143722}, {-0.452792, 0.948832, 0.0503916, -0.0143722, -0.976465}}}
```

i used this code to get inverse of two matrix

```
-Inverse[#] & /@ t1
```

and get result as follows

```
 {{{0.527757, -0.00787528, 1.18541, -0.147178,  0.0305467}, {-0.00787528, 0.0565341, 0.0108403, 3.99541,0.0543206}, {1.18541, 0.0108403, 4.04155, 0.314973, 0.339589}, {-0.147178, 3.99541, 0.314973, 321.241,  2.95482}, {0.0305467, 0.0543206, 0.339589, 2.95482, 1.02171}}, {{1.27371, -0.0158652, 7.07499, -0.110165, -0.239306}, {-0.0158652, 0.0920673, -0.0282588, 1.31093, 0.0760653}, {7.07499, -0.0282588, 46.2561, -0.477807, -0.914032}, {-0.110165, 1.31093, -0.477807, 23.8719, 0.948899}, {-0.239306, 0.0760653, -0.914032, 0.948899, 1.14785}}}
```

i used this code with another two nested list named t2 as follows

```
t2={{{-5.3632, -6.748, 1.69453, 0.0854, -0.29345}, {-6.748, -171.6,  2.159, 2.23, 3.710}, {1.69453, 2.159, -0.83467, -0.02813, 0.18637}, {0.0854, 2.23, -0.02813, -0.0321, -0.03390}, {-0.29345, 3.710, 0.186366, -0.03390, -1.19279}}, {{-5.239, -2.180, 0.7379, 0.13145, -0.4176}, {-2.180, -53.481, 0.3282, 2.9460,  1.2974}, {0.7379, 0.3282, -0.1231, -0.01940, 0.04261}, {0.13145, 2.9460, -0.01940, -0.20926, -0.02945}, {-0.4176, 1.2974,  0.04261, -0.02945, -1.00586}}}

-Inverse[#] & /@ t2
```

but i get this error what's wrong?
[image: error]

Comment: Inverse gives the inverse of a square matrix. When I look at your matrix using MatrixForm[t1] it is not square. Are you trying to compute the inverse of a matrix? Or an inverse in some other sense? Can you post an example on a shorter list of what your expected outcome should be?

Comment: Sorry, I see you use it applied to the square submatrices

Comment: In MMA version 13.1 your code runs o.k. And the inverses are far from being ill conditioned.

Comment: I use Mathematica 11 version. thanks Daniel Huber

Answer (score 3):

If `-Inverse[#] & /@ t2` does not work in 11 version,we maybe test

```
-LinearSolve[#, IdentityMatrix[5]] & /@ t2
```

In 13.1 version, all of them work.

```
(-Inverse[#] & /@ t2) - (-LinearSolve[#, IdentityMatrix[5]] & /@ 
    t2) // Chop
```

[image]